# Should I use a different shader for each light type in OpenGL renderer

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am making a relatively simple render for a physics engine (something similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfonMfP__Ks)). I am just learning OpenGL and have been following this [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/#!Introduction). I want my renderer to be able to handle a small number of lights chosen from the types: directional, point, spotlight, and area light. Also I want simple shadows using shadow maps. So for example a scene might contain two spotlights or one directional light or one point light and one spotlight etc. Currently I have one larger shader that handles all the lights together, however now that I am experimenting with shadow maps it seems light it would be better (from a modular design perspective) to have a different shader for each light or at least each light type. I am wondering if this is a reasonable idea from the perspective of efficiency. To make this more concrete my current vertex looks like:

```
#version 130 

in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec2 atexture;

out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 lightView;
uniform mat4 lightProjection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = normalize(normal);
    TexCoord = atexture;

    FragPosLightSpace = lightProjection * lightView * vec4(FragPos, 1.0f);
}
```

and fragment shader:

```
#version 130

struct Material
{
    float shininess;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct DirLight
{
    vec3 direction;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

struct SpotLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutOff;
    float outerCutOff;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;       
};

struct AreaLight
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;   
};

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec4 FragPosLightSpace;

uniform Material material;
uniform DirLight dirLight;
uniform PointLight pointLight;
uniform SpotLight spotLight;
uniform AreaLight areaLight;

uniform vec3 cameraPos;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

float CalcShadow(vec4 FragPosLightSpace);
vec3 CalcDirLight(Material material, DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcPointLight(Material material, PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcSpotLight(Material material, SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);
vec3 CalcAreaLight(Material material, AreaLight light);

void main(void) 
{
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(cameraPos - FragPos);

    vec3 finalLight = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    finalLight += CalcDirLight(material, dirLight, Normal, viewDir);

    finalLight += CalcPointLight(material, pointLight, Normal, FragPos, viewDir);

    finalLight += CalcSpotLight(material, spotLight, Normal, FragPos, viewDir);

    finalLight += CalcAreaLight(material, areaLight);

    FragColor = texture2D(texture1, TexCoord) * vec4(finalLight, 1.0f);
}


float CalcShadow(vec4 fragPosLightSpace)
{
    // only actually needed when using perspective projection for the light
    vec3 projCoords = fragPosLightSpace.xyz / fragPosLightSpace.w;

    // projCoord is in [-1,1] range. Convert it ot [0,1] range.
    projCoords = projCoords * 0.5 + 0.5;

    float closestDepth = texture(shadowMap, projCoords.xy).r;

    float currentDepth = projCoords.z;

    float bias = 0.005f;
    float shadow = currentDepth - bias > closestDepth  ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;

}


vec3 CalcDirLight(Material material, DirLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 viewDir)

{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(-light.direction);

    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);

    float ambientStrength = 1.0f;
    float diffuseStrength = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    float specularStrength = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);

    float shadow = CalcShadow(FragPosLightSpace);

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * material.ambient * ambientStrength;
    vec3 diffuse = (1.0f - shadow) * light.diffuse * material.diffuse * diffuseStrength;
    vec3 specular = (1.0f - shadow) * light.specular * material.specular * specularStrength;

    return (ambient + diffuse + specular);
}


vec3 CalcPointLight(Material material, PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);

    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);

    float ambientStrength = 1.0f;
    float diffuseStrength = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    float specularStrength = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), material.shininess);

    float attenuation = 1.0f / (1.0f + 0.01f*pow(length(light.position - fragPos), 2));

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * material.ambient * ambientStrength;
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * material.diffuse * diffuseStrength;
    vec3 specular = light.specular * material.specular * specularStrength;

    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;

    return vec3(ambient + diffuse + specular);
}


vec3 CalcSpotLight(Material material, SpotLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);

    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);

    float ambientStrength = 0.05f;
    float diffuseStrength = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    float specularStrength = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), material.shininess);

    float attenuation = 1.0f / (1.0f + 0.01f*pow(length(light.position - fragPos), 2));

    float theta = dot(lightDir, normalize(-light.direction));
    float epsilon = light.cutOff - light.outerCutOff;
    float intensity = clamp((theta - light.outerCutOff) / epsilon, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * material.ambient * ambientStrength;
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * material.diffuse * diffuseStrength;
    vec3 specular = light.specular * material.specular * specularStrength;

    ambient *= attenuation * intensity;
    diffuse *= attenuation * intensity;
    specular *= attenuation * intensity;

    return vec3(ambient + diffuse + specular);
}


vec3 CalcAreaLight(Material material, AreaLight light)
{
    // return vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    return vec3(2*material.ambient);
}
```

What I would like to do is separate each light type out to a different shader so instead of having one "ubershader" I would have a directionalLight shader and a spotlight shader etc. Is this a good idea? In particular I am worried that switching shaders multiple times for each render call might be expensive?

Comment: The physics in the video is complex, the renderer I don't think is? Perhaps you are right that the answer would be broad (although I didn't know that). Is using multiple shaders in each rendering pass considered a good idea? Or is that too dependent on other factors?

Comment: Sorry perhaps you were referring to rendering the water as being complex. Let me simplify the problem by saying I will only use rigid bodies and so I am only rendering a bunch of objects. I will be including water in my engine using marching cubes and SPH but we can assume its just rigid bodies for this question.

Comment: This depends on *a lot* of factors, you should start be evaluating what kind of render pipeline you want to build and why. Do you want to stick to forward rendering or maybe go Forward+ or one of the deferred flavors(vanilla, tiled, clustered)? Whats your target platform, whats important to you(performance vs simplicity), what is the scope of the project(as in what features do you need down the road)? The simplest solution is the one you already have, metaphorically speaking. If its not a problem don't fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is too broad and doesn't fit into SO format. However I will try to answer it, mostly because it is frequently asked by beginners to engine programming.
To manipulate different shader setups for lighting and shadowing you have got 2 standard practices:

1. **"Uber-shader"**

The idea behind this is that you have every possible case embedded into this shader. So for example, you want to be able to render up to 4 light sources (I am talking here of [forward-rendering](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_Rendering)), so you insert a `for` loop with max number of lights, and then pass a uniform (number of lights in the scene) to tell the loop in the real time how many times to iterate. Then, if you enable the shadow pass, you also pass a uniform into the uber-shader to activate an "if" condition for shadow map sampling. As you already can see, this way is quite inefficient. You will end up with complex branching all over your shader, and will have to submit multiple uniforms during runtime to change the shader state. All this impacts performance and usability. Well, you can simplify this a little, by using OpenGL 4.0 [subroutines](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Subroutine). But generally speaking - don't do it.

2. **Shader permutations**

This is a quite industry common way and while it is more complex to design and setup such a system, it pays off on the long run. The idea is that you configure your shaders code, based on use case scenario in run-time, (or if you have offline shader compiler available,then you can even do this in compile time), so at the end you get a shader string contain the code for the specific rendering setup. For example, if your scene has 2 lights + shadows, and a material a renderable object uses diffuse and normal map, then you configure the shaders for that material to generate a code to handle 2 lights, shadow mapping , diffuse and normal maps sampling. It would take me too much time and space here to write in detail how to design and code such a system. But generally speaking, you write a sort of shader templates, full of pre-processor flags for different permutations. You inject pre-processor flags for specific permutation type, then compile shaders and shader program. In top-notch game engines like Unity3D and Unreal, all possible shader permutations are generated already in editor during authoring time. If you roll your own engine, just compose required permutation during runtime and throw that into shader compiler. With long shader strings you will notice a slight freeze during online compilation, but if you cache and then reuse already compiled permutations of the shader programs, you are going to be fine.

**Bonus part**

You can also, do that as you proposed - prebuild the different variations of shaders, which is effectively my number 2 approach. But your proposal is problematic, because if you wrap a single light rendering logic into separate program, that would mean in case of a scene with 2 light sources:

1 - Render the object with first light source.

2 - Render the object with second light source.

Compose two frames into final result. This already requires 3 render passes and takes you more to the direction of [deferred shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading), which is a quite advanced technique and not always what you need unless your plan is to develop an engine to deal with huge amounts of geometry and light sources.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you know of any good resources that give more details about shader and renderer design, in particular the shader permutations method you describe? I have heard of the deferred shading method before but I don't think it is appropriate for my project as it would be more hassle than its worth given I will only have a few lights and generally my camera will be pointing at one thing most of the time.

Comment: Possibly mention additive blending as well, if each light source has its own shader. But yeah, that will practically eliminate the argument for not doing deferred already. :)